# inode i_private field to store private data

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel, linux-device-driver

If I need to store data specific to an inode, could I use this field?
The context is a linux module I'm writing that needs to hold a certain struct per inode (where every device of this module has an inode).

I know that in file descriptors, I can store data in the private_data field. Is i_private the "corresponding" field for inode?

Answer (score 1):

This field is used by fs drivers. Excerpt from ext4.h:

```
static inline ext4_io_end_t *ext4_inode_aio(struct inode *inode)
{
    return inode->i_private;
}

static inline void ext4_inode_aio_set(struct inode *inode, ext4_io_end_t *io)
{
    inode->i_private = io;
}
```

So, if you're writing your own filesystem then it's totally ok. But if you're using inodes from existing filesystem you should not do this because you will corrupt inodes.

Comment: Is there a field, like private_data in file descriptor struct, that I can use to store my own data without corrupting the inode?

Comment: What are you doing with inodes?

Comment: I'm creating a character device module named 'abc'.
And I need to store a struct for each device ('abc0', 'abc1',...), so each user that will call open() for example on a specific device will get the corresponding struct of the device.
i.e. if 2 processes call open(abc0,..) they could access the same struct.

Comment: This is just the way I thought to accomplish this (through inserting data into inode). If there is a standard, more elegant way, I'm all in.

Comment: You can embed `struct cdev` in your struct and use `container_of` on `inode->i_cdev` to get your struct associated with registered char device. Look for examples in LDD3, chapters [about registration](http://makelinux.com/ldd3/chp-3-sect-4) and [open/release methods](http://makelinux.com/ldd3/chp-3-sect-5)

Comment: I read the LDD3 and the urls you posted. Still something not in place for me. I've implemented the init_module() method, open and release.
Do I need also to implement the "struct cdev cdev = {...}" where instead of "..." i'll add the fields I need, and then call cdev_init and cdev_add? then what? when I have my hands on the inode pointer, I will call container_of(inode->i_cdev) and that will be my modified cdev struct?